# omnipay - AuthorizeNet_CIM

Tags: omnipay, authorize.net-cim

I am trying to setup a payment processor using **omnipay-authorizenet AuthorizeNet_CIM**. Not a lot of documentation on this.

**Step 1)** I create the gateway object successfully and can make requests to the authorize.net sandbox server.

**Step 2)** is to "create a card" for future use with Token Billing: $gateway->createCard() . This is successful.

From the **General Omnipay Token Billing documentation**:

"... createCard($options) - returns a response object which includes a cardReference, which can be used for future transactions..."

I don't see a specific 'cardReference' in the above createCard() response object.

So I create a $cardRef array and grab the returned response CustomerProfileId and CustomerPaymentProfileId .

```
$profileResult['customerProfileId']=$response->getCustomerProfileId();

$profileResult['paymentProfileId']=$response->getCustomerPaymentProfileId();
```

**Step 3)** is a function to generate the purchase which fails:

```
function create_transaction($cardRef,$amount,$description,$invoice_number){

global $status, $gateway;

try {

// Send purchase request
$response = $gateway->purchase(
    array(
        'cardReference' => $cardRef ,               
        'amount' => $amount,
        'currency' => 'USD',                
        'description' => $_POST['description'],
        'transactionId' => $invoice_number

    )
)->send();          
if ($response->isSuccessful()) {

    // Payment was successful       
    $status.='Success: '.$response->getMessage();

} elseif ($response->isRedirect()) {

    // Redirect to offsite payment gateway
    $response->redirect();

} else {        

    // Payment failed
    $status.='Transaction Failure: '.$response->getMessage();

}       

} catch (Exception $e) {

    $status.='<strong>Error:</strong> '.$e->getMessage(). "<br/>";

}       

}
```

The purchase fails and when I look at the Response object it seems the Request is not populating the **cardReference** object.

```
[cardReference] => Omnipay\AuthorizeNet\Model\CardReference Object
(
[customerProfileId:Omnipay\AuthorizeNet\Model\CardReference:private] =>
[paymentProfileId:Omnipay\AuthorizeNet\Model\CardReference:private] =>
[shippingProfileId:Omnipay\AuthorizeNet\Model\CardReference:private] =>
)
```

I am obviously not passing the correct **cardReference** data to the purchase method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I apparently needed to use the undocumented Omnipay method;

```
$response->getCardReference();
```

to get a cardReference object to pass to my create_transaction() function.

All fixed.

Thanks